# Слайдер не правильно считает слайды / Массивы, JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Изучаю JS, решил попробовать написать слайдер, столкнулся с такой проблемой, последний элемент массива почему-то повторяется, то есть когда мы переключаемся на него, нажав повторно на стрелку `next` он повторяется вместо того чтобы перейти к 0 элементу, буду благодарен если укажите на мои костыли и подскажите как можно это исправить, спасибо!

```
var prev = $('a.prev');
var next = $('a.next');

var arrTestimonials = {
    firstName: ["1", "2", "3"],
    projectName: ["1", "2", "3"],
    testimonialsText: ["1", "2", "3"]
};

$('div.slide h4').text(arrTestimonials.firstName[0]);
$('div.slide p.testimonial-text').text(arrTestimonials.testimonialsText[0]);
$('div.slide p.project-name span').text(arrTestimonials.projectName[0]);

i=0;

prev.click(function () {
    if (i == 0) {
        i = arrTestimonials.firstName.length;
        $('div.slide h4').text(arrTestimonials.firstName[i]);
        $('div.slide p.project-name span').text(arrTestimonials.projectName[i]);
    }
    else {
        i--;
        $('div.slide h4').text(arrTestimonials.firstName[i]);
        $('div.slide p.testimonial-text').text(arrTestimonials.testimonialsText[i]);
        $('div.slide p.project-name span').text(arrTestimonials.projectName[i]);
    }
});
next.click(function () {
    if (i == arrTestimonials.firstName.length) {
        i = 0;
        $('div.slide h4').text(arrTestimonials.firstName[i]);
        $('div.slide p.testimonial-text').text(arrTestimonials.testimonialsText[i]);
        $('div.slide p.project-name span').text(arrTestimonials.projectName[i]);
    }
    else {
        i++;
        $('div.slide h4').text(arrTestimonials.firstName[i]);
        $('div.slide p.testimonial-text').text(arrTestimonials.testimonialsText[i]);
        $('div.slide p.project-name span').text(arrTestimonials.projectName[i]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас путаница с индексом элементов массива. Счетчик никогда не должен быть равен длине массива, так как счет начинается с нуля. Проверка должна выглядеть так:

```
next.click(function () {
    if (i == arrTestimonials.firstName.length - 1) {
       ...
    }
    ...
});
```